# How to add a widget only for design time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Inspired by the [tools attributes](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes) which allow to override layout properties when using the UI designer in Eclipse/Android Studio but without any effect on the running application I would like to have **entire widgets stripped away**:

I have a LinearLayout which is populated with several children at runtime. To visualize this in the UI editor, I added two dummy views to the layout xml which are then deleted using [removeAllViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews%28%29) at runtime.
This means that the dummy views are needlessly generated just to be removed shortly after.

Is there a way to define the views as dummies using something similar to the "tools"-attribute?

Comment: use LayoutInflater.Filter for conditional view loading

Comment: Thanks, this would be one step towards the right direction. But contrary to the tools attribute, this requires some non-trivial processing. Additionally, the knowledge about what is a dummy view and what not is moves from the xml file to the implementation (as it is in my current approach and which I want to get rid of)

Comment: so make the custom container view and override its addView method and call super.addView conditionaly